# How to find if username exist inside a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created an archive(usersfile.txt) that contains the users information,
i want when i insert the username, if the username exist in the file return that the user exists and to refer me to the profile of the user(the profile is ok).Τhe problem is that i cannot find the user in the file.

The file is like:

```
{'user': 'mark', 'age': '20', 'city': ' london '},
{'user': 'jason', 'age': '28', 'city': ' london '},
{'user': 'john', 'age': '25', 'city': ' london '},
{'user': 'pit', 'age': '24', 'city': ' london '}
```

When i insert the first username ('mark) it works but when i insert the other usernames doesn't work.any suggestion?

is it better to do it with regex?(but i don't know how)

```
username = input('Enter Username:')

   with open(usersfile.txt, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f :
    userfiles=[]
    for userf in f:
      userf = userf.split()
      userfiles.append(userf)

   for names in userfiles:
    if username in names:
      print('User {} exist :'.format(username))
      UserProfile()
      return True
    else:
      print('User {} doesn't exist :'.format(username))
      return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> user_props = {'user': 'mark', 'age': '20', 'city': ' london '},
{'user': 'jason', 'age': '28', 'city': ' london '},
{'user': 'john', 'age': '25', 'city': ' london '},
{'user': 'pit', 'age': '24', 'city': ' london '}
>>> # to find the person
>>> for person in user_props:
       user_name = person.get('user')
       if user_name and user_name == 'mark':
           print(person)
{'user': 'mark', 'age': '20', 'city': ' london '}
>>> # just check if mark is a user
>>> any([it for it in user_props if it.get('user') is 'mark'])
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
the person is random not only mark and  the users information is in a file. i must first transfer the users from file to dict.

Comment: The file you posted is not a dict. It's a tuple. A dict would require encapsulation with `{}` you would need to cook the data to get a dict from that format.

Regex is a really bad way to find json values and will only lead to hating regex for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do a binary search as this will be the fastest for searching a file of say usernames. For more information on a binary search look at [this library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html) for Python and [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/). Another more purely vanilla Python way would be to load in the JSON and then loop through each user.

### (Bad) Way

We load in the JSON with either an eval or the JSON library. Since you don't want to use other modules we'll use an eval. This is bad for many reasons mainly security and bugs that can break the program.

```
with open("users.txt") as f_in:
  eval("data="+f_in.read())
```

Now that we have the "JSON" loaded in a variable, `data`, we can loop through the list of dictionaries and test for your user.

```
for u in data:
  if u["user"] == user:
    print("Found user: "+str (u))
    break
```

---

### Binary Search Method

One of the first things you'll want to do is sort the file, also making it either CSV or JSON will help rather than just plain text. I think CSV is best in this case so we'll create a `users.csv` file with the following content.

```
user,age,city
jason,28,london
john,25,london
mark,20,london
pit,24,london
```

And then our Python code will load the file and get the first column of user names. The most efficient way to do the binary search would be to keep the usernames sorted from the start. So when appending a name to the file or list of users you must insert it at the correct index such that the list will be sorted.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from bisect import bisect_left

with open("users.csv") as f_in:
    df = pd.read_csv(f_in)
    f_in.seek(0)
    rows = [r for r in csv.reader(f_in)]

pos = bisect_left(df.name, user)
pos = pos if pos != len(df.name) and df.name[pos] == user else -1

if pos < 0:
    print("The user was not found.")
else:
    properties = "\n".join([x for x in rows[pos+1]])
    print(f"User: {user} was found with properties:\n{properties}")
```

Comment: thanks for te answer!
The file it must remain the same as i post it and i can't use any module only (regex if i want)

Comment: @hR_Der in that case, sort the list of names before searching them and then create your own binary search. However, if it's just a small file going through each user might work just as fast so (badly) load the file into a variable using `eval` and then loop through them instead of doing a split or something.